# Print data from a $watch input

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm pretty new on AngularJS but I have to develop a search tab which prints a `$http.get` `JSON`.

My logic is to attach a `ng-model` with a `$watcher` and print the data.

Am I doing it correctly? Is there any other recomendation to do it better?

Here bellow I paste the code:

**discover.js**

```
var discover = angular.module('app.discover', ['discover.factory']);

discover.controller('getDiscover', [ '$scope', 'img', 'search', function ($scope, img, search) {

  var data = this;

  $scope.$watch('searchStr', function (substring) {
    if (substring && substring.length > 1) {
      search.getJSON(substring).then(function (response) {
        data.stories = response.stories;
        data.tags = response.tags;
        data.users = response.users;
      });
    }
  });
}]);
```

**_discover.html**

```
<div style="padding-top:50px;">
  <article>
    <section>
      {{my.stories}}
      {{my.tags}}
      {{my.users}}
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Investigating much more I was missunderstanding the real issue which I'm gonna try to explain.

```
.state('discover', {
   url: "/discover",
   views: {
      'header': { templateUrl: "app/Topbar/_topbarDiscover.html", controller: 'getDiscover', controllerAs: 'my' },
      'content': { templateUrl: "app/Discover/_discover.html", controller: 'getDiscover', controllerAs: 'my' },
      'footer': { templateUrl: "app/Navbar/_navbar.html", controller: 'NavbarController', controllerAs: 'my' }
   }
});
```

The main problem here is I understood that writing the same `controller` meant I was using the same `controller` for the 2 `ui-views`, but the fact is the first `controller` was calling the action, so it was the topbar `controller: getDiscover` which had the data.

Comment: Are you getting anything in `response` from service `getJson` method?

Comment: @Dev-One With a `console.log` as a response I get the `object`

Comment: What does the `object`  have?

Comment: It throws a object that contains 3 `json`, stories, tags and users

Comment: And what do you need to do with the object now?

Comment: Print it in the `html` as a result of a search

Comment: everything in the object?  Please see the answer below, it shows if its a json  then you would have to parse it, and assign to `$scope` or else just assign it in the `$scope` and print it in the view.

Comment: I have updated my post, please keep it an eye @Dev-One

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this would be to use an associative array to keep object literals as to what needs to be print in

```
$scope.print = {stories: '', tags: '', users: ''};
```

You could use `$watch` here as it will monitor any change in model `$scope.searchStr`. Keep in mind, this function gets called even when single character is enter into the model. You could look into `ng-blur` from the angularJS API docs as an alternative.

```
$scope.$watch('searchStr', function (substring) {
    if (substring && substring.length > 1) {
      search.getJSON(substring).then(function (response) {
        //parse Json
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(response.data);

        $scope.print.stories = parsedData.stories;
        $scope.print.tags = parsedData.tags;
        $scope.print.users = parsedData.users;
      });
    }
});
```

The service using `$http` , `$resource` returns a payload in form of `response.data`. Since, your service returns a JSON, you would need to parse it before printing it on the view.

```
<div style="padding-top:50px;">
  <article>
    <section>
      {{print.stories}}
      {{print.tags}}
      {{print.users}}
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```